# clean_session in pahoMqtt , python not working

Tags: python, pyqt5, mqtt

I'm using mosquitto 1.5.7 to run a server on rpi 0 which takes the logs from something, and publish it to a topic:

```
class LiveLogServer:
    def __init__(self, hostname, port, numPos):
        self.broker = hostname
        self.port = port
        self.numPos = numPos
        self.status = True
        self.stopThread = True
        self.topicPublish = '/logServers/logServer{numPos}/live'
        self.topicSubscribe = '/logServers/logServer/serials'
        self.client = mqtt.Client()
        self.connect_mqtt()
        self.client.on_message = self.on_message
        self.subscribe(self.topicSubscribe)
        self.startListen()

    #start a log for a specific tid in a thread
    def startStreamingLog(self, tid):
        os.system('adb logcat -c')
        self.p = Popen(['adb', '-t', str(tid), 'logcat', '-v', 'brief', 'example:V', '*:S'],
                        stdout=PIPE, bufsize=-1, close_fds=ON_POSIX)
        self.q = Queue()
        self.t = Thread(target=self.process_logline, args=(self.p.stdout, self.q))
        self.t.daemon = True # thread dies with the program
        self.t.start()
        self.logs()

    def process_logline(self, out, queue):
        for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
            queue.put(line)
        out.close()

    #read all the logs from a camera
    def logs(self):
        while self.status:
            try:
                line = self.q.get_nowait() # or q.get(timeout=.1)
            except Empty: #queue is empty here, do nothing
                continue
            else: # got line from log
                print(line)
                lineTemp = str(line.decode('utf-8').rstrip())
                self.publish(lineTemp)

    def connect_mqtt(self):
    # Set Connecting Client ID
        self.client.connect(self.broker, self.port)
        self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.client.on_message = self.on_message
        return self.client

    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Started LiveLogServer for pos [{}]".format(self.numPos))
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

    #receive the serial from the client, get the tid for that serial abd start streaming the logs
    def on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):
        print(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
        currentID = CameraID().getLatestTID(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
        print(currentID)
        self.startStreamingLog(currentID)


    def subscribe(self, topic):
        self.client.subscribe(topic)

    def publish(self, msg):
        publish.single(self.topicPublish, msg, hostname=self.broker)

    def startListen(self):
        self.client.loop_start()
```

And I made a GUI with PyQT5 who subscribe to the topic and take the messages, parse them and apply some rules on each line.

```
class Ui_logWindow(QtCore.QObject):
    messageSignal = pyqtSignal(str)
    logWindowSignal = pyqtSignal(str) 
    output_GUI = ''
    
    def showLogs(self):
        arg1 = self.lineEdit.text()
        arg2 = int(self.lineEdit_2.text())
        arg3 = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        arg4 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        arg5 = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        arg6 = self.lineEdit_6.text()
        self.client = ClientLogParser(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6)
        self.client.client.on_message = self.onMsgWin
        # self.client.client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnectHere
        self.messageSignal.connect(self.appendToLog)
        self.appendLogShortcut = self.messageSignal.emit
        self.logWindowSignal.connect(self.appendToLogWindow)
        self.appendLogWindowShortcut = self.logWindowSignal.emit
        self.t = Thread(target = self.client.startListen, args=[])
        self.t.daemon = True
        self.t.start()

    def submit(self):
        self.plainTextEdit_2.clear()
        self.showLogs()
    
    def on_disconnectHere(self):
        print('on disconnect here')
        self.client.client.disconnect()
        

    def appendToLog(self,msg):
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(msg)
        self.plainTextEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)

    def appendToLogWindow(self,msg):
        self.plainTextEdit_2.appendPlainText(msg)
        self.plainTextEdit_2.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)

    def onMsgWin(self, client, userdata, msg):
        self.listMsg = msg.payload.decode('utf-8').rstrip()
        self.appendLogWindowShortcut(self.listMsg)
        for line in self.listMsg.split('\n'):
            self.client.lp.parseEvent(line)
            self.client.rp.evaluateDict(self.client.lp.dictLogs)
            self.output_GUI += "COUNT:\n"
            for key, val in self.client.lp.dictLogs.items():
                self.output_GUI += f"EVT[{key}] COUNT[{val}]\n"
                if val > 0:
                    self.output_GUI += f'------ the event : {key} has been triggered ------\n'
            self.output_GUI += "RULES:\n"
            for rule_idx in range(len(self.client.rp.dictRulesList)):
                if self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx] == 'critical':
                    sys.exit(-1)
                if self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx] == 'warning':
                    self.output_GUI += '----------succes----------\n'
                if self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx] == 'info':
                    self.output_GUI += '----------succes----------\n'
                if self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx] == 'succes':
                    self.output_GUI += '----------succes----------\n'
                self.output_GUI += f"RULE:[{rule_idx}][{self.client.rp.dictRulesList[rule_idx]}]\n"
                self.output_GUI += f"RESULT[{rule_idx}][{self.client.rp.resultList[rule_idx]}]\n"
            self.output_GUI += "----ITERATION-END----\n"
            self.appendLogShortcut(self.output_GUI)
```

```
class ClientLogParser:

    def __init__(self, hostname, port, serial, numPos, lp_path, rp_path):
    self.broker = hostname
    self.port = port
    self.serial = serial
    self.numPos = numPos
    self.lp = LogParserLive(lp_path)
    self.rp = ReportParserLive(rp_path)
    self.topicPublish = '/logServers/logServer{numPos}/live'
    self.topicSubscribe = '/logServers/logServer/serials'
    self.client = mqtt.Client(clean_session=True)
    self.connect_mqtt()
    # self.client.on_message = self.on_message_local
    self.publishSerial(serial)
    self.subscribe(self.topicPublish)
    self.running = False
    # self.startListen()   

def connect_mqtt(self):
    # Set Connecting Client ID
    # self.client.reinitialise(clean_session=True)
    self.client.connect(self.broker, self.port)
    self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
    self.client.on_message = self.on_message
    self.client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect
    return self.client

def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print(f"Started pinServer for pos [{self.numPos}]")
    else:
        print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

def on_disconnect(self, client, userdata, rc):
    print('disconnected')

def on_message_local(self, client, userdata, msg):
    msg.payload.decode('utf-8')


def subscribe(self, topic):
    self.client.subscribe(topic)

def publishSerial(self, msg):
    publish.single(self.topicSubscribe, msg, hostname=self.broker)

def startListen(self):
    self.running = True
    self.client.loop_start()
    print('connected')
    self.looping()

def looping(self):
    while self.running:
        sleep(.5)
```

The thing is the GUI is working as I expect when I click on Submit, after that I click on Stop and it's stopping taking the logs from the server. BUT when I click AGAIN on submit the same log line is doubled, if I do again stop and submit the lines are tripled and so on.
Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: a very good question.   it sounds like you are not destroying the existing instance and are creating more and more instances....

Comment: Agree with @D.L but currently it's difficult to see how the bits fit together (i.e. what is called when you click 'Stop'/'Submit') and the code is incomplete. Please try to produce a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (this probably does not need any QT code). I suspect that you will find the issue while attempting to create the example.

Comment: Also, unrelated to the issue reported, please note that Mosquitto 1.5.7 is fairly old (released Feb 2019) so you may wish to consider updating.

Comment: I've updated the whole code, so LiveLogParser is the class who's starting the server, QT class call the ClientLogParser for connecting and disconnecting. 
@Brits I know this but when I try on my rpi 0 sudo apt-get install mosquitto it tells me : mosquitto is already the newest version (1.5.7-1+deb10u1). 
On my pc I have mosquitto: Installed: 1.6.9-1. I also tried with clear_start = 1 but this is working only on MQTT V5 which is mosquitto v2.0.14 and even so I got the same result after updating mosquitto

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, in QT class every time I was instantiate the signals and connect them without disconnect them.

```
class Ui_logWindow(QtCore.QObject):
messageSignal = pyqtSignal(str)
logWindowSignal = pyqtSignal(str)
```

So I disconnect them in my disconnect method:

```
def on_disconnectHere(self):
    print('on disconnect here')
    self.messageSignal.disconnect()
    self.logWindowSignal.disconnect()
    self.client.client.disconnect()
```